# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured, Cannot find the circular import or issues in url

Tags: python, django

I followed the Django tutorial in the official [website](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/) however I get the following error.

polls/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import index

url_patterns = [
    path('',index,name='index')
]
```

Tut/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Comment: There's a typo in your first file. Compare how you've written the list name in both ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your polls.urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import index

urlpatterns = [
   path('',index,name='index')
]
```

remove the underscore from **url_patterns**

it will work